# Compare two image in real time with predefined image with real time capture image in Opencv c++

Tags: c++, opencv

I am doing a project of Automatic fabric defect detection. In this i developed the algorithm using the [FFT][1] (Fast Fourier Transform) and its working fine in my Ubuntu 14.04 `opencv c++`. But now i want to develop this to real time there i have to capture image every 2s and have to process that image with my developed algorithm. I need ideas on how to capture images using webcam in `opencv c++` and to process withat same image which is being captured. Please do help me if anyone knows of this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You may want to take a look at: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html In particular, take a look at the VideoCapture class. I'd also suggest improving your question a bit by making it more readable and by making clear what you really want and what is important to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow the guidance which has given by OpenCV - They have provided enough [examples](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html) such as following sample code. Following code is provided by OpenCV Dev team as sample.

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

using namespace cv;

int main(int, char**)
{
    VideoCapture cap(0); // open the default camera
    if(!cap.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
        return -1;
   Mat edges;
   namedWindow("edges",1);
   for(;;)
   {
       Mat frame;
       cap >> frame; // get a new frame from camera
       cvtColor(frame, edges, CV_BGR2GRAY);
       GaussianBlur(edges, edges, Size(7,7), 1.5, 1.5);
       Canny(edges, edges, 0, 30, 3);
       imshow("edges", edges);
      if(waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
   }
   // the camera will be deinitialized automatically in VideoCapture       destructor
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you for ur help as it works fine , but i do have a problem tht i have written a code tht captures image every 30ms and save. but i am unable to open that image in a window. its running in a while loop.